# Oracle 9i default login, it did not ask me to setup any login during installation, what will be default login and pass?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle9i

I installed Oracle 9i Enterprise, and when it was installed i got an error in configuration manager, but it installed rest of all the things and it said that configuration manager is an optional so you can install it later. Anyway when i opened enterprise manager, and created a schema, it asked for username and password, i am sure it is asking for user like SYSTEM or SYS, but neither it required me to set any login info, nor i changed it. Can you please tell me how to set it easily, if i do SQL Plus, it asks for username and password. Don't know its science. Attaching image
[image]

Comment: Why did you choose a completely unsupported (and outdated) Oracle version as a new installation?

Comment: I know its old, i have 11G too but problem is the VB6 app was built in 2003 and it was compatible with Oracle 9i only, we need to run it.

Answer (score 1):

The default passwords are listed in the documentation, in a couple of places, but if you've installed a starter database then [this](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95493_02/startrdb.htm) might be most appropriate. I have to agree with a_horse_with_no_name though, installing such an old version seems like an odd thing to do.